# Webscraping A Table Using Python and BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm learning on how to webscrape using Python since I'm a novice. Right now, I attempted to webscrape Euros 2020 stats from this website https://theanalyst.com/na/2021/06/euro-2020-player-stats. After running my initial code (see below) to gather the html from the webpage, I cannot locate the table tag and its data-table class. I can see the table and its data-table when I inspected the website, but it is not shown when I print out the page_soup.

```
from urllib.request import urlopen as uReq  # Web client
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup  # HTML data structure

url_page = 'https://theanalyst.com/na/2021/06/euro-2020-player-stats'

# Open connection & download the html from the url
uClient = uReq(url_page)

# Parses html into a soup data structure
page_soup = soup(uClient.read(), "html.parser")
uClient.close()

print(page_soup)
```

Answer (score 1):

The table is loaded dynamically in JSON format via sending a `GET` request to:

```
https://dataviz.theanalyst.com/euro-2020-hub/player_stats_3_2020.json
```

Since we're dealing with JSON data, it's easier to use the `requests` library to get the data.

Here is an example using the `pandas` library to print the table into a `DataFrame` (you don't have to use the `pandas` library).

```
import pandas as pd
import requests

url = "https://dataviz.theanalyst.com/euro-2020-hub/player_stats_3_2020.json"
response = requests.get(url).json()

print(pd.json_normalize(response["data"]).to_string())
```

Output (truncated):

```
    player_id  team_id        team_name           player_first_name           player_last_name                 player  age    position     detailed_position  mins_played  np_shots  np_sot  np_goals  np_xG  op_chances_created  op_assists  op_xA  op_passes  op_pass_completion_rate  tackles_won  interceptions  recoveries  avg_carry_distance  avg_carry_progress  carry_w_shot  carry_w_goal  carry_w_chance_created  carry_w_assist  take_ons  take_ons_success_rate  goal_ending  total_xG  shot_ending                                                                                                                                   team_badge
0       103955      114          England                      Raheem                   Sterling        Raheem Sterling   26     Forward        Second Striker          641        14       8         3   3.82                   2           1   1.18        193                     0.85            5              4          23               12.98                6.73             3             0                       3               1        38                  52.63            6      7.08           24  https://omo.akamai.opta.net/image.php?secure=true&h=omo.akamai.opta.net&sport=football&entity=team&description=badges&dimensions=150&id=114
1        56979      114          England                      Jordan                  Henderson       Jordan Henderson   31  Midfielder    Central Midfielder          150         1       1         1   0.32                   0           0   0.06        111                     0.88            0              1          11                7.83                0.49             0             0                       0               0         3                  66.67            0      0.00            0  https://omo.akamai.opta.net/image.php?secure=true&h=omo.akamai.opta.net&sport=football&entity=team&description=badges&dimensions=150&id=114
2        78830      114          England                       Harry                       Kane             Harry Kane   27     Forward               Striker          649        15       7         4   3.57                   5           0   0.39        159                     0.70            0              3           8               10.52                3.06             2             0                       2               0        15                  53.33            7      6.38           21  https://omo.akamai.opta.net/image.php?secure=true&h=omo.akamai.opta.net&sport=football&entity=team&description=badges&dimensions=150&id=114
3        58621      114          England                        Kyle                     Walker            Kyle Walker   31    Defender             Full Back          599         0       0         0   0.00                   2           0   0.18        352                     0.87            0              8          37               11.66                5.09             0             0                       0               0         1                 100.00            3      2.54           10  https://omo.akamai.opta.net/image.php?secure=true&h=omo.akamai.opta.net&sport=football&entity=team&description=badges&dimensions=150&id=114
```

The variable `response` is now a dictionary (`dict`) which you can access the keys/values. To view and prettify the data:

```
from pprint import pprint

print(type(response))
pprint(response)
```

Output (truncated):

```
<class 'dict'>
{'data': [{'age': 26,
           'avg_carry_distance': 12.98,
           'avg_carry_progress': 6.73,
           'carry_w_assist': 1,
           'carry_w_chance_created': 3,
           'carry_w_goal': 0,
           'carry_w_shot': 3,
           'detailed_position': 'Second Striker',
```

Comment: Thank you! Quick question, how do you know it's in JSON data format? Also, where did you find the json link (https://dataviz.theanalyst.com/euro-2020-hub/player_stats_3_2020.json)? I inspected the actual webpage, but I don't see it. Again, thank you.

Comment: @SlopersPinches If you open your Developer Tools in your browser (usually the F12 key) under the "Network" tab you can see all the network calls